# Will I get -2 for an edit in removed question?

Tags: discussion, edits

I've edited some questions and some of them are deleted.

So its showing that -2 in  my score sheet.  What does it mean?

The +2 point I got is removed or I'm getting a negative point for the edited post (which is removed)?

This made me doubt:

[image]

Here If I'm not getting negative why my total score became zero in **2 days ago**. It should be 6, right ?

Comment: What does `-ve` mean?

Comment: `-ve` means negative

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The -2 Cancels out the +2 for the edit so you are no better off (or worse off for that matter) prior to editing the question

Comment: you are worse off for the wasted time and effort

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: But if you're really lucky, the user may have learned from your example so the chances of the next question being closer to good are at least infinitesimally higher. :)

Comment: @Matt Thank you for your reply, see the updated question. It looks like I lost the point gained through editing and got -2 extra too..

Answer (score 39):

The points you received for doing the editing are lost when the question containing the edit is lost.

It's one of the risks of editing and improving questions which are likely to be beyond recovery and eventually removed.

Comment: In other words, don't bother to edit a question such as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30457123/cant-find-published-app-on-play-store) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30448946/unable-to-use-the-horoscope-api-correctly-in-android-studio). Or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30437037/create-customize-sliding-tabs). (Good news is, you seem to have a knack for finding bad questions. Now all you have to do is earn Vote To Close.)

Comment: .. and anyway, flagging for closure and downvoting are already available options.

Comment: I'll make these edits anyways if its a new user and I think the edit shows them how to improve their future posts. A lot of times the entire post is later removed, but that is a risk of editing from the first posts queue.

Comment: @Brian Thank you for your reply. Please see the updated question.

Comment: It looks like I lost the point gained through editing and got -2 extra too..

Comment: @RapunzelEugene - The +2 for the edits for the posts removed was awarded many days ago. The +2 shown in your post are for more recent unremoved edits. As Matt explained, each -2 is preceded by an earlier +2.